# How to adapt this comparison function for table sorting

Tags: javascript

This will sort alphabetically, but before the a's b's etc.. I want anything that begins with `[` then anything that begins with `.`.

How to do that?

```
function ts_sort_default(a,b) {
  aa = ts_getInnerText(a.cells[SORT_COLUMN_INDEX]);
  bb = ts_getInnerText(b.cells[SORT_COLUMN_INDEX]);
  if (aa==bb) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (aa<bb) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add these lines

```
function ts_sort_default(a,b) {
  aa = ts_getInnerText(a.cells[SORT_COLUMN_INDEX]);
  bb = ts_getInnerText(b.cells[SORT_COLUMN_INDEX]);

////
if(aa.substr(0,1) == '[') {
        if(bb.substr(0,1) == '[') {return 0;} else {return 1;}    
}

if(bb.substr(0,1) == '[') {
    return -1; // aa is known not to be "["    
}

if(aa.substr(0,1) == '.') {
    if(bb.substr(0,1) == '.') {return 0;} else {return 1;}    
}

if(bb.substr(0,1) == '.') {
    return -1;    
}

////

if (aa==bb) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (aa<bb) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

(I am not much into JS, so doublecheck the syntax.)

Comment: hmm, cant seem to get it to work, still sorting as usual, ill keep trying to fix it and see

Comment: @user1166981 Thanks for accepting the answer. You wrote it did not work right out of the box - did you adapt something? I would integrate it into my answer for fellow developers.

Comment: oh sorry, no actually it was the rest of the function causing it not to work, your code works perfectly. thanks

Comment: ah, i spoke too soon, it doesn't appear to make a difference